# Arrêter, suspendre, surseoir ou finir ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

*Administrativement parlant*, do we say "arrêtez svp de m'envoyer des e-mails" or "terminez svp..." or something else like "finissez", "surseoir", "suspendre"?

I have no idea about that? What is the most polite and that suits the administration world?

Answer (score 4):

> Arrêtez S.V.P. de m'envoyer des e-mails

est correct.

La phrase la plus administrativement élaborée serait de dire :

> Je vous prie de bien vouloir ne plus m'importuner avec vos courriels.

En revanche :

> Par avance, merci de supprimer mon adresse de vos listes d'envoi

peut être très efficace, car ni agressive, ni familière la phrase correspond à la nétiquette, qui demande aux  sites de fournir à l'internaute une possibilité de se faire rayer des listes de diffusion.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following verbs might suit, depending on the language level or the amount of angryness you want

- arrêter
- cesser
- stopper (anglicism though)
- mettre un terme
- mettre fin à

Comment: Not angry at all, i want to be as polite as possible.

Comment: In this case, you could even use the heavy "Je vous saurais gré de cesser vos envois d'e-mails"